# What is the purpose of `contextWithCGContext:options:` method?

Tags: objective-c, core-image

I treated `CIContext` as a kind of abstract state collector, which purpose is to allow `CIFilter`s to function.

But there is `+[CIContext contextWithCGContext:options:]` function which accepts `CGContextRef` as its input.

What does it mean? If this `CGContextRef` already contains some graphics, then how it will be used in newly created `CIContext`?

Will the contents of `CGContextRef` affect `CIFilters` in any way?

Is it possible to output `CIImages`, produced by `CIFilters`, into this initial `CGContextRef`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it mean? If this `CGContextRef` already contains some graphics, then how it will be used in newly created `CIContext`?

`CIContext` can be backed by the `CGContext`, and used to draw the filtered data on top of the context's content.

> Is it possible to output `CIImages`, produced by `CIFilters`, into this initial `CGContextRef`?

(Almost) any `UIView` class sets a `CGContext` shortly before calling `drawRect:` method, and if you are not going to produce an `UIImage`/`CIImage` object, but instead just want to override this method and draw the result of your filters, you can get use of [`-[CIContext drawImage:inRect:fromRect:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1437786-drawimage) in order to render your (e.g. filtered) data to the context of this view:

```objc
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() options:nil];
    CIImage *input = self.image.CIImage;

    CIFilter *filter = [[self class] makeFilter];
    [filter setValue:input forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    [context drawImage:filter.outputImage
                inRect:rect
              fromRect:filter.outputImage.extent];
}
```

> Will the contents of `CGContextRef` affect `CIFilters` in any way?

Not exactly, `CIFilter`s objects in isolation don't get affected by any side effects of `CGContext` state currently active. However if the `CGContext` itself has any transformation in place, it won't be discarded of course:

```objc
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextRotateCTM(cgContext, radians(-45.));

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:cgContext options:nil];
    ... Applies CIFilter sequence ...
   
    // The result will be both filtered and rotated by 45 degrees counterclockwise
    [context drawImage:filter.outputImage
                inRect:rect
              fromRect:filter.outputImage.extent];
}
```